# creating block device for portwoks container using chef kitchen

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I wana test a protworks container using chef and for that i require one block device created by vagrat as driver in .kitchen.yml file till now what i was doing is this.

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  customize:
   createhd:
     filename: /dev/xvdb.vmdk
     size: 1024
   storageattach:
     storagectl: SATA Controller
     port: 1
     device: 0
     type: hdd
     medium: /dev/xvdb.vmdk
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  # You may wish to disable always updating cookbooks in CI or other testing environments.
  # For example:
  #   always_update_cookbooks: <%= !ENV['CI'] %>
  always_update_cookbooks: true

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: centos-7.3

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[pwx_cookbook::default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/smoke/default
    attributes:
".kitchen.yml" 34L, 659C
```

and this is not working so any suggestion would make a great help.

Comment: You can manually check the generated `Vagrantfile` under the `.kitchen/` folder.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot  coderanger , actually i saw that before too but manually configured after u said it too.